# Google Cloud Platform autoscaler is too sensitive

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have an instance group that reports an HAProxy metric to StackDriver. This instance is configured to auto scale based on that metric. The capacity for each instance is 300.

Now, the issue is mostly the value 0, and when it goes to 1 (out of 300 capacity!) a new instance is created and deleted immediately. This is really odd behavior, and the same use case doesn't happen in our QA environment ( on a different project)

How can I debug this?

**Load Balancer configuration:**

```
ig  us-east1    3 / 3   Target LB capacity fraction 100%    Max RPS: 1000 (per instance)    100%
```

**Autoscaler configuration**

```
Autoscaling
On
Autoscaling policy
HTTP load balancing usage
Target HTTP load balancing usage
100%
Minimum number of instances
1
Maximum number of instances
2
```

[image: Auto scaling graph]

Comment: Can you provide more details? How is the autoscaler configuired? Can you provide more info about the metric? The autoscaler itself should have a target metric and should scale the group up or down to try and have the average load meet the target. This is not ideal if you have a metric that fluctuates frequently

Comment: I added a screenshot of capacity / utilization of the instance group. As you can see, the utilization is no where near the capacity yet instances are added and dropped randomly..

Comment: you are balancing based off of LB capacity with a target of 100%. That is not something the autoscaler can maintain properly. Once you reach more than 1000 rps per instance, the autoscaler will try to scale up and then the RPS per instance drops drastically. Since you only have between 1 and 2 instances, target CPU utilization may be better

Comment: but that's not the issue. Look at the graph, any reasons why it should scale up?

Comment: the metric you are using is 1. the target is 1, that makes the LB calculation much more difficult and less room to navigate. Also note that the autoscaling is based on the RPS and not the custom metric shows in that graph. Your LB autoscaler is controlling the size of the group

Comment: @PatrickW The metric never got to 1..

Answer (score 1):

A resource you can look into is the following: [Scaling Based on HTTP(s) Load balancing serving capacity](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/scaling-cpu-load-balancing#scaling_based_on_https_load_balancing_serving_capacity)

One thing to note in the article is the following “Autoscaling only works with maximum CPU utilization and maximum requests per second/instance because the value of these settings can be controlled by adding or removing instances”.

The HTTP load balancer will create and remove instances following the back end configurations that the managed instance group is using. The load balancer has some monitoring graphs that you can look into to get more insights.

I wasn’t able to recreate the behavior your graph shows with the settings you provided.

The HTTP load balancer back end service’s health check rules could be good to see. You can compare it with your QA environment's rules to confirm if all other variables are identical or not.